# How can static method access class variable in Python?

Tags: python

This is what my code looks like

```
class InviteManager():
    ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE = "You are already on our invite list"
    INVITE_MESSAGE = "Thank you! we will be in touch soon"

    @staticmethod
    @missing_input_not_allowed
    def invite(email):
        try:
            db.session.add(Invite(email))
            db.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            return ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE
        return INVITE_MESSAGE
```

When I run my tests, I see

```
NameError: global name 'INVITE_MESSAGE' is not defined
```

How can I access `INVITE_MESSAGE` inside `@staticmethod`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can access it as `InviteManager.INVITE_MESSAGE`, but a cleaner solution is to change the static method to a class method:

```
@classmethod
@missing_input_not_allowed
def invite(cls, email):
    return cls.INVITE_MESSAGE
```

(Or, if your code is really as simple as it looks, you can replace the whole class with a bunch of functions and constants in a module. Modules are namespaces.)

Comment: Or just make it a module-level function.

Comment: @delnan: yes. Sometimes you need a class or static method, though, in particular in situations involving inheritance or duck typing.

Comment: Any idea why python allows to access `class variable` via `staticmethod`? 
If so why do we need `classmethod`? What is the different use case between `classmethod` and `staticmethod` if they both can access the class variables?

Comment: class methods get a reference to the subclass, so they can be written in a baseclass but work differently in different subclasses, as they behaviour can depend on the class.

also, static methods don't get a reference to the class, so using cls is cleaner if you need to refer the class at all, for example as the code does not break if the name of the class changes.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
class InviteManager():
    ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE = "You are already on our invite list"
    INVITE_MESSAGE = "Thank you! we will be in touch soon"

    @staticmethod
    @missing_input_not_allowed
    def invite(email):
        try:
            db.session.add(Invite(email))
            db.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            return InviteManager.ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE
        return InviteManager.INVITE_MESSAGE
```

The `InviteManager` is in the scope of it's staticmethods.

Answer (score 7):

It is much simpler than all of that:

Just added `__class__` to the class variables.
Like so:

```
return __class__.ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE
        return __class__.INVITE_MESSAGE
```

There is no need to mention the ClassName (InviteManager) and there is no need to use a `classmethod`

Comment: More information: The `__class__` [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23757143/8944057) was introduced in [PEP 3135](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/).

Answer (score 5):

Just realized, I needed `@classmethod`

```
class InviteManager():
    ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE = "You are already on our invite list"
    INVITE_MESSAGE = "Thank you! we will be in touch soon"

    @classmethod
    @missing_input_not_allowed
    def invite(cls, email):
        try:
            db.session.add(Invite(email))
            db.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            return cls.ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE
        return cls.INVITE_MESSAGE
```

You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

**Simply, understand the concept of class level variables/methods and instance level variables/methods.**

While working with static methods, you won't use **self** keyword as **self** keyword is used to represent instance of the class or to use instance variables of the class. In fact one use **class_name**, see below example:

```
class Myclass():
    msg = "Hello World!"

    @staticmethod
    def printMsg():
        print(Myclass.msg)



Myclass.printMsg() #Hello World!
print(Myclass.msg) #Hello World!
Myclass.msg = "Hello Neeraj!"
Myclass.printMsg() #Hello Neeraj!
print(Myclass.msg) #Hello Neeraj!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access to yours attributes with `InviteManager.INVITE_MESSAGE` and `InviteManager.ALREADY_INVITED_MESSAGE` without changing anything in their declaration.