# What is a cell in the context of an interpreter or compiler?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, closures, interpreter, rust

Python code objects have an attribute [`co_cellvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=co_cellvars#index-55). The documentation to [PyPy's bytecode interpreter](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/interpreter.html?highlight=cell#code-class) often uses the term *Cell*.

Among other langauges, Rust [provides a Cell datatype](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.10/std/cell/index.html). Googling suggests they relate to closures somehow.

What is a *cell*, in the context of a programming language implementation? What problem do cells solve?

Comment: In Rust, `Cell` is just a way of getting around inherited immutability so that you can modify data despite having an immutable reference to it. This is quite a different thing to what Python means by it. "Cell" is a pretty generic term, you know.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan sounds like you're familiar with Cell in both the contexts I mention. Would you be willing to submit an answer?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the internals of the Python code object representation, but I can guess at what it is meaning by "cell".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Python, `cell` objects are used to store the [free variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variable) of a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

Let's say you want a function that always returns a particular fraction of its argument. You can use a closure to achieve this:

```
def multiplier(n, d):
    """Return a function that multiplies its argument by n/d."""
    def multiply(x):
        """Multiply x by n/d."""
        return x * n / d
    return multiply
```

And here's how you can use it:

```
>>> two_thirds = multiplier(2, 3)
>>> two_thirds(7)
4.666666666666667
```

How does `two_thirds` remember the values of `n` and `d`? They aren't arguments to the `multiply` function that `multiplier` defined, they aren't local variables defined inside `multiply`, they aren't globals, and since `multiplier` has already terminated, its local variables no longer exist, right?

What happens is that when `multiplier` is compiled, the interpreter notices that `multiply` is going to want to use its local variables later, so it keeps a note of them:

```
>>> multiplier.__code__.co_cellvars
('d', 'n')
```

Then when `multiplier` is called, the value of those outer local variables is stored in the returned function's `__closure__` attribute, as a tuple of `cell` objects:

```
>>> two_thirds.__closure__
(<cell at 0x7f7a81282678: int object at 0x88ef60>,
 <cell at 0x7f7a81282738: int object at 0x88ef40>)
```

... with their names in the `__code__` object as `co_freevars`:

```
>>> two_thirds.__code__.co_freevars
('d', 'n')
```

You can get at the contents of the cells using their `cell_contents` attribute:

```
>>> {v: c.cell_contents for v, c in zip(
        two_thirds.__code__.co_freevars,
        two_thirds.__closure__
)}
{'d': 3, 'n': 2}
```

You can read more about closures and their implementation in the Python Enhancement Proposal which introduced them: [PEP 227 — Statically Nested Scopes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/).

Comment: Is it possible to modify one of these stored variables to alter the function after creation? (e.g. d = 5)

Comment: @EdwardGaremo Yes you can: ```c.cell_contents = 5```. More general: ```func.__closure__[func.__code__.co_freevars.index(name)].cell_contents = value```.